# Keystonejs admin ui : View field instead of id for relationships

Tags: keystonejs

It's a pretty simple issue :

When I have a `name` field in a List that I set a relationship to, the relationship shows properly the name of the linked document. For example, in that List I have a field named `business` that has a relationship on a `Business` List which has a `name` field.

[image: Business name shown properly]

But when my relationship is to a List that has no `name` field, only the id is shown in the admin UI like this :

[image]

Which is obviously very impratical.

How can I configure keystone to show a specific field in the admin ui to represent the document?

Answer (score 2):

Keystone only shows the `name` field as a document header or relationship summary.

But there is a simple solution to use a custom field as a `name` field : the `map` option. When creating the model, map the field you want to display to the `name` field.

For example, I have localized text fields, and I want to display the english version by default :

```
const LocalizedText = new keystone.List('LocalizedText', {
  map: { name: 'en' } // <=== This is the solution
});

LocalizedText.add({
  fr: { type: String },
  en: { type: String }
});

LocalizedText.register();
```

[Here is the documentation :](https://keystonejs.com/api/list/options/)

> **map**
>
> An object that maps fields to special list paths. Each path defaults to its key if a field with that key is added. Mappable paths include
>
> **name** - the field that contains the name of the item, for display in the Admin UI.

Answer (score 2):

I know it´s an old question but had the same problem, I leave here how I fix it in Keystone 5 hoping it helps someone else.

You just have to add a labelField when creating the list with the field name you want to be displayed instead the id.

```
keystone.createList('User', {
  fields: {
    name: { type: Text },
    email: { type: Text },
  },
  labelField: 'name',
});
```

Documentation [here](https://www.keystonejs.com/api/create-list)

Comment: You can also use 'labelResolve' for customized label:

Answer (score 0):

Example of customized label:

```
const Post = {  
fields: { 
    title: { type: Text },
    // other fields
  },
  labelResolver: item => item.title,
};
```

Using more logic:

```
  const Post = {
  fields: {
    title: { type: Text },
    status: {
      type: Select,
      defaultValue: 'draft',
      options: [
        { label: 'Draft', value: 'draft' },
        { label: 'Published', value: 'published' },
      ],
    },
    // and the rest of the fields too
  },
  labelResolver: item => `${item.status === 'draft' ? 'DRAFT - ' : ''}` + item.title,
};
```

Using query result:

```
  const Post = {
  fields: {
    author: {
      type: AuthedRelationship,
      ref: 'User',
      isRequired: true,
    },
    // and the rest of the fields too
  },
  labelResolver: async item => {
    const { data } = await keystone.executeGraphQL({
      query: `query {
          User(where: {id: "${item.author}" }) {
            name
          }
        }`,
    });

    return `${item.status === 'draft' ? 'DRAFT ' : ''}` + item.title + ` (${data.User.name})`;
  },
};
```

Details from keystoneJs's blog:
[Using customized label](https://v5.keystonejs.com/blog/better-ux-with-custom-labels)